# How can I set up a camera at bird's eye view using GLM?

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, glm-math, perspectivecamera

I am trying to set up my camera at a bird's eye perspective. By that I mean pointing straight down. This is what I've initialized so far:

```
glm::vec3 camPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);  // camera's position
glm::vec3 camFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // where the camera is pointing
glm::vec3 camUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

I pass this into the `glm::lookat` function but this is not working at all. Perhaps I haven't understood it that well...

Comment: Do you know how the OpenGL works and that `glm::lookat` has return type of matrix 4x4 and what you need to do with that matrix?

Comment: Yes I do (at least I think I do...). I am multiplying that matrix with the position matrix of my object.

Comment: I am not an expert but maybe you need to invert the matrix you get from `lookat`

Comment: hmm.. doesn't seem to be working

Comment: What does *not working* mean? This code should give you a correct view matrix.

Comment: @NicoSchertler by not working I mean it is not looking straight down like I want it to, it's looking straight ahead

Comment: That is not really possible. Are you sure your models have the orientations that you think they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to set up my camera at a bird's eye perspective.

I recommend to do the following. Define 2 vectors.

1. Define the up vector of the world. This means the vector, which points form the ground to the sky, in the coordinate system of your world:

   ```cpp
    glm::vec3 world_up( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
   ```
2. Define the direction to the north in the coordinate system of your world:

   ```cpp
    glm::vec3 world_north( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
   ```

With this information the vectors of the view coordinates system can be set up.

1. `camPosition` is the position of the "bird". A point hight up in the sky:

   ```cpp
   float height = 10.0f;
   glm::vec3 camPosition = world_up * 10.0f;
   ```
2. `camTraget` it the position where the "bird" is looking at. A point on the ground:

   ```cpp
   glm::vec3 camTraget = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
   ```
3. `camUp` is perpendicular to the vector from `camPosition` to `camTraget`. Since the "bird" looks at the ground it is the flight direction of the bird (e.g. to the north):

   ```cpp
   glm::vec3 camUp = world_north;
   ```

With this vectrs the view matrix can be set up by [`glm::lookAt()`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00668.html#gaa64aa951a0e99136bba9008d2b59c78e):

```cpp
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt( camPosition, camTraget, camUp );
```